# KMS Generated Signature Is Too Large

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to use AWS KMS to generated a signature for a JWT but am getting back a signature that appears to be too large for the algorithm I've chosen.  I am using Node.js and the [AWS KMS Client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-sdk/client-kms) to generate the signature.

```js
const header64 = base64url.encode(JSON.stringify(header));
const payload64 = base64url.encode(JSON.stringify(payload));

const message = Buffer.from(`${header64}.${payload64}`);

const command = new SignCommand({
    KeyId: 'mrk-1234567890',
    Message: message,
    SigningAlgorithm: SigningAlgorithmSpec.ECDSA_SHA_256
});

const client = new KMSClient({});
const response = await client.send(command);

const signature64 = base64url.encode(Buffer.from(response.Signature), 'base64');

const jwt = `${header64}.${payload64}.${signature64}`;
```

When I think try and verify this JWT I get an error message saying

> "ES256" signatures must be "64" bytes, saw "71"

This number of 71 bytes matches the size of the Uint8Array contained in the `response.Signature`.  The verification is being done using the generated public key and the [jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken) package.

Am I missing something glaringly obvious here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ended up being a misunderstanding of what was being returned by the AWS SDK.  According to the docs:

> When used with the ECDSA_SHA_256, ECDSA_SHA_384, or ECDSA_SHA_512 signing algorithms, this value is a DER-encoded object as defined by ANS X9.62–2005 and RFC 3279 Section 2.2.3.

What this means is that I needed to perform one final step on the returned signature before adding it to my JWT.  Using the [ecdsa-sig-formatter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ecdsa-sig-formatter) package my final code takes the following shape:

```js
const header64 = base64url.encode(JSON.stringify(header));
const payload64 = base64url.encode(JSON.stringify(payload));

const message = Buffer.from(`${header64}.${payload64}`);

const command = new SignCommand({
    KeyId: 'mrk-1234567890',
    Message: message,
    SigningAlgorithm: SigningAlgorithmSpec.ECDSA_SHA_256
});

const client = new KMSClient({});
const response = await client.send(command);

const signature64 = base64url.encode(Buffer.from(response.Signature), 'base64');
const signatureJose = derToJose(signature64, 'ES256');

const jwt = `${header64}.${payload64}.${signatureJose}`;
```

Comment: I can't upvote this enough, can I buy you a beer??? I was going completely crazy on the signature being invalid, this saved me.